# ant build android project failed

Tags: android, ant, build

I build android project using ant apache. and I get this error

```
[javac] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

I don't modify any ant *build.xml*; I just replace *android.jar* with other *android.jar* in sdk.dir/platforms/android-18, it I don't replace with other *android.jar*, I will get errors.
The new *android.jar* has some extra useful classes to link with.

so, what's the problem about this error? Any help, highly thinks.

Comment: after adding the respective jars refresh and update the project before building it.

Comment: using 'android update project -p .' to updating project. also get the same errors